# failed to get status code from returned jqXHR of $.post call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to post and insert a row of record to the end of table body by registering submit event listener. Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8jew8kk7/4/

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  jx = $.post('data.asp', 'action=add&' + $(this).serialize())
  console.log("jx=" + jx.status)
  if (jx.status == 404) {
    alert("404 not found")
    return false
  }
  tdstring = "<tr><td>" + $("input[name='pkeyEmployeeID']").val() + "</td><td>" + $("input[name='strFirstName']").val() + "</td><td>" + $("input[name='strLastName']").val() + "</td><td>" + $("input[name='dtmBirthDate']").val() + "</td><td>" + $("input[name='strHomePhone']").val() + "</td>"
  delstring = '<td><button type="button" name="action" value="del" onclick="del(this)" fid="' + $("input[name='pkeyEmployeeID']").val() + '">add</button></td></tr>'
  $(this).find('tbody').append($(tdstring + delstring).hide().fadeIn('normal'))
})
```

But `jx.status` always `undefined` while running. When execute `x=$.post('data.asp').status` in Chrome console I can get the code exactly  server returns. Is there any flaws with this snippet?

Comment: try changing input[name='pkeyEmployeeID' to input[name='pkeyEmployeeID'] first in the strings

Comment: @ABUdhay thanks for pointing out. I should add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you code runs asynchronously `console.log("jx= " + jx.status)` runs before the ajax request completes and thus there is no such thing as statusfor jx object and thus it returns undefined. In order to use it , run it inside the `.always()` function. Also you need to use selector like this `$("input[name='pkeyEmployeeID']")` instead of `$("input[name='pkeyEmployeeID'")`

```
jx.always(function(){
    alert( jx.status)
    if (jx.status == 404) {
      alert("404 not found")
      return false
    }

  })
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8jew8kk7/5/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.post ( or $.post) method return a promise object. So if you want to get data from jqXHR, you have to get it from then(), always() or fail() method of promise.

```
jx = $.post('data.asp', 'action=add&' + $(this).serialize())
jx.always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if(jqXHR.status == 200)
    //your code here
})
```

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information). These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.)
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8jew8kk7/14/